# Add RequestMapping to controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I got a controller

```
@Controller
public class ModxProxyController
{
    @RequestMapping("/face/blog")
    public ModelAndView processFace()
    {...}
}
```

It only processes request to URL /face/blog. And i need it to process (in the same method) more URLs. But to the moment my app starts I don't know that URLs. I can retrieve them once a day from 3rd party service. So the task is - programmatically add URLs to be processed with this method (`processFace`).

Answer (score 2):

you could use `regexp` in

```
  @RequestMapping("/face/regexp")
```

example:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{textualPart:[a-z-]+}.{numericPart:[\\d]+}")
public String regularExpression(
  @PathVariable String textualPart,
  @PathVariable String numericPart){

    System.out.println("Textual part: " + textualPart + 
      ", numeric part: " + numericPart);
    return "someResult";
}
```

from http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-mvc-requestmapping-example

Comment: I can`t do it with regular expression, beacouse i dont know the URLs i will need to process. I can only retrieve them proggrammatically. So i need to make request mapping also programmatically.

Comment: @user2160696 you did't understood the main idea. you have to write `only one functions` for one `type of url`.

Comment: I dont have any "type of url". It can be /face/dodo, /face/dddd or even /faceee. And for all this array of URLs i got the special logic. For all other URLs i got premapped methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need some form of common root, eg :

```
@RequestMapping("/face/*")
```

Or even just everything

```
@RequestMapping("/")
```

Comment: Nope, i got already premapped logic for /. I need my method to process array of URLs i retrieved from 3rd party service. They can be any (/face/ff, /face/dd or even /dodo/do). And i need all this URLs be mapped directly to my method.

Comment: @user2160696 so just face or dodo as the root ?

Comment: Гnfortunately i dont know the root url. It can be any. So the only way - is to set this mapping directly.

Comment: @user2160696 that is a bit more difficult http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?103772-dynamic-RequestMapping-behavior

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can define requestmappings with property placeholders. If this is possible i would write a property evaluator that fetches these mappings "once a day". You could implement this lookup against a database if needed or even a property file.